# Unable to get response from $.get

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

```
zip = 12345
url = "http://zip.elevenbasetwo.com/v2/US/"+zip; 
res = $.get(url)
```

When I run above code in the browser console then I can access `res.responseJSON` but
When I run this code in my application.js then I can't access `res.responseJSON` I am getting undefine.

Does anybody know what's the issue or how can I access in my application.js ?

Comment: is it the code you are running exact?

Answer (score 1):

[$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) is **asynchronous**. The response isn't immediatement available in the jqXHR object.

Pass a success callback to `$.get` :

```
$.get(url, function(data){
   // use data
});
```

The reason why it seems to work in the console is because you don't instantly open the object which is logged : the server answers before. That's not the case in your normal code : while the request is sent, the following line in your code is immediately executed, without waiting for the answer.

Comment: how to return value and get out side that function?

Comment: you can't. See this related answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call